# Cumulative count of values in R

Tags: r, average, cumulative-sum

I hope you are doing very well. I would like to know how to calculate the cumulative sum of a data set with certain conditions. A simplified version of my data set would look like:

```
t   id  
A   22
A   22
R   22
A   41
A   98
A   98
A   98
R   98
A   46
A   46
R   46
A   46
A   46
A   46
R   46
A   46
A   12
R   54
A   66
R   13 
A   13
A   13
A   13
A   13
R   13
A   13
```

Would like to make a new data set where, for each value of "id", I would have the cumulative number of times that each id appears , but when t=R I need to restart the counting e.g.

```
t   id  count
A   22  1
A   22  2
R   22  0
A   41  1
A   98  1
A   98  2
A   98  3
R   98  0
A   46  1
A   46  2
R   46  0
A   46  1
A   46  2
A   46  3
R   46  0
A   46  1
A   12  1
R   54  0
A   66  1
R   13  0
A   13  1
A   13  2
A   13  3
A   13  4
R   13  0
A   13  1
```

Any ideas as to how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we assume that your dataframe never has non-adjacent `id` values, e.g.  there are no other "41" values further on?

Comment: Yes, there are no other values further on, because it is previously ordered by another column (the time sequence of each id and t). 
I think @Arun solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `rle`:

```
out <- transform(df, count = sequence(rle(do.call(paste, df))$lengths))
out$count[out$t == "R"] <- 0
```

If your `data.frame` has more than these two columns, and you want to check only these two columns, then, just replace `df` with `df[, 1:2]` (or) `df[, c("t", "id")]`.

If you find `do.call(paste, df)` dangerous (as @flodel comments), then you can replace that with:

```
as.character(interaction(df))
```

I personally don't find anything dangerous or clumsy with this setup (as long as you have the right separator, meaning you know your data well). However, if you do find it as such, the second solution may help you.

---

#### Update:

For those who don't like using `do.call(paste, df)` or `as.character(interaction(df))` (please see the comment exchanges between me, @flodel and @HongOoi), here's another base solution:

```
idx <- which(df$t == "R")
ww <- NULL
if (length(idx) > 0) {
    ww <- c(min(idx), diff(idx), nrow(df)-max(idx))
    df <- transform(df, count = ave(id, rep(seq_along(ww), ww), 
                   FUN=function(y) sequence(rle(y)$lengths)))
    df$count[idx] <- 0
} else {
    df$count <- seq_len(nrow(df))
}
```

Comment: I find that `do.call(paste0, df)` a dangerous approach for finding identical rows. Would welcome something more robust.

Comment: Do you mean using `paste` instead of `paste0` (then, yes I understand)? If not, I don't quite get what's dangerous? Could you provide an example of the scenario you're referring to?

Comment: 1) (the main concern) imagine if `df` had more than those two columns of interest 2) not the case with the OP's data, but pasting can theoretically lead to matches that are not, e.g. `rle(paste0(c("ab", "a"), c("c", "bc")))`. Having to consider that possibility and having to choose a data-dependent separator as to avoid these situations makes the approach a little cumbersome and icky.

Comment: @flodel, Point taken, but I disagree (not being rude). The example you show is what I mention in my comment earlier (and changed `paste0` to `paste`). But expecting data like `c("a_", "c")` and `c("a", "_c")` is a bit too much IMHO (and if so, yes we've to change the separator). With `regexp` one does data-dependent stuff all the time (I don't find it new or cumbersome). I guess then `interaction` function from base shouldn't be used as well from what you say? In any case, I'll write back with an alternative base solution (if I find one) for those who agree with you.

Comment: @arun: `paste` will lose the distinction between `a ` and `b`, and `a` and ` b`. This problem is present regardless of the separator used, or if no separator is used (`paste0`). `interaction` will not, and in general doesn't depend on assumptions about text content.

Comment: @HongOoi, I don't think so (iiuc). Did you try `paste(c("a", "a"), c("b", " b"))`?

Comment: Not sure why markdown didn't like it, but there should be a space before that second b of mine. Both will result in `"a  b"`. Note that if you use `interaction`, you shouldn't have to use `as.character` at all.

Comment: @HongOoi, I understand that there was a space there. And my command does have a space. You'll find that the resulting vector has 1 and 2 spaces respectively. Just copy/paste the command.

Comment: @HongOoi, I use `rle` on the `interaction` output. It doesn't work with `factors`. Hence the `as.character(.)`.

Comment: Yes, but my example was `paste("a ", "b")` and `paste("a", " b")`. Also, you could use `as.numeric` instead of `as.character` for factors which avoids text issues entirely.

Comment: @HongOoi, that's not different from what @flodel pointed. You compare `paste` that uses default separator as `space` with `interaction` which uses `.` as default separator. It's not fair. To illustrate my point, try this to see `paste` and `interaction` give the same output: `df <- data.frame(x=c("a ", "a"), y=c("b", " b")); do.call(paste, (df, sep=" ")); as.character(interaction(df, sep = " "))`

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I'd call that a bug in `interaction`, really; it should be able to handle text clashes in level names in a smarter way.

Comment: Sorry, but once again I disagree. I don't think it's a bug and it's about knowing your data. I may want to separate `"a"` from `"a "`,  which is what `interaction` does. If I don't want them to be different, then I can replace trailing spaces and then use `interaction`. But if it does that by default, I lose the first option of distinguishing between "a" and "a ".

Comment: Thank you @Arun. The first approach runs faster than the second. I've changed the second code in line 5 to x <- transform(df, count =...) because I got an error (object 'x' not found). Thank you all!

Comment: Yes, `as.numeric(interaction(c("a.", "a"), c("b", ".b")))` gives you `c(1, 1)`. If this is not a bug, this is a VERY undesirable feature. Like I said earlier, it is very cumbersome to have to consider that possibility and hence have to choose a separator that will not break given your data. `interaction` should do that for free IMHO.

Comment: @arun: at least you did not disagree regarding *1) (the main concern) imagine if df had more than those two columns of interest*

Comment: @flodel, yes I do agree with (1) although I find it more of a minor than a major concern. On the `interaction` *bug* comment, if `x <- c("a", "a ")`, then you'd expect `as.factor(x)` to have just 1 level?

Comment: no two levels, why? I don't see how this relates? Let's take it to the chat!