# Summarize data already grouped in r

Tags: r, reshape, summary

With the following dataset in R
ID=Custid

```
ID Geo Channel Brand Neworstream RevQ112 RevQ212 RevQ312
1  NA  On-line  1      New         5         0       1
1  NA  On-line  1      Stream      5         0       1
3  EU  Tele     2       Stream     5         1       0
```

I would like to convert the dataset to this format of columns

```
ID Geo Brand Neworstream OnlineRevQ112 TeleRevQ112 OnlineRevQ212 TeleRevQ212
```

What is the best way to go about doing this? Can't figure out the best command in R.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `reshape` from base R or `reshape2` from `reshape2`package

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `reshape2` package and its `melt` and `dcast` functions to restructure your data.

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 3L), Geo = structure(c(NA, NA, 
1L), .Label = "EU", class = "factor"), Channel = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("On-line", "Tele"), class = "factor"), Brand = c(1L, 
1L, 2L), Neworstream = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("New", 
"Stream"), class = "factor"), RevQ112 = c(5L, 5L, 5L), RevQ212 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), RevQ312 = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "Geo", "Channel", 
"Brand", "Neworstream", "RevQ112", "RevQ212", "RevQ312"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)) 

library(reshape2)
## melt data
df_long<-melt(data,id.vars=c("ID","Geo","Channel","Brand","Neworstream"))

## recast in combinations of channel and time frame
dcast(df_long,... ~Channel+variable,sum)
```

Comment: right, I missed that. Used a different name when I imported locally.

Comment: +1 although I'm not sure if `reshape` is in development anymore. Probably you should use `reshape2`.

Comment: +1. As @Arun mentions, an update to reshape2 is probably advisable, though the only difference required in this solution would be changing `cast` to `dcast`.

Comment: @Arun, I changed the dependency to reshape2 per your advice.

Answer (score 2):

### Update/facepalm

The "NA" in your dataset probably aren't `NA` values but rather, the abbreviation "NA" for North America or something like that.

If you had used `na.strings` when reading your data in, you should have no problems using `reshape` as I originally indicated:

```
mydf <- read.table(header = TRUE, na.strings = "", 
text = 'ID Geo Channel Brand Neworstream RevQ112 RevQ212 RevQ312
1  NA  On-line  1      New         5         0       1
1  NA  On-line  1      Stream      5         0       1
3  EU  Tele     2       Stream     5         1       0')

reshape(mydf, direction = "wide",
        idvar = c("ID", "Geo", "Brand", "Neworstream"),
        timevar = "Channel")
```

(I might, however, recommend changing your abbreviation for legibility and to reduce confusion!)

---

#### Original Answer (since there's still something interesting about `reshape` there)

This should do it:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = c("ID", "Geo", "Brand", "Neworstream"), 
        timevar = "Channel")
#   ID  Geo Brand Neworstream RevQ112.On-line RevQ212.On-line RevQ312.On-line
# 1  1 <NA>     1         New               5               0               1
# 3  3   EU     2      Stream              NA              NA              NA
#   RevQ112.Tele RevQ212.Tele RevQ312.Tele
# 1           NA           NA           NA
# 3            5            1            0
```

---

#### Update (To try to salvage the answer a little bit)

As @Arun points out, the above isn't quite right. The culprit here is `interaction()`, which is used by `reshape()` to create a new temporary ID variable when more than one ID variable is specified.

Here's the line from `reshape()` and what it looks like when applied to our "mydf" object:

```
data[, tempidname] <- interaction(data[, idvar], drop = TRUE)
interaction(mydf[c(1, 2, 4, 5)], drop = TRUE)
# [1] <NA>          <NA>          3.EU.2.Stream
# Levels: 3.EU.2.Stream
```

Hmmm. This seems to simplify to two IDs, `NA` and `3.EU.2.Stream`.

What happens if we replace `NA` with `""`?

```
mydf$Geo <- as.character(mydf$Geo)
mydf$Geo[is.na(mydf$Geo)] <- ""
interaction(mydf[c(1, 2, 4, 5)], drop = TRUE)
# [1] 1..1.New      1..1.Stream   3.EU.2.Stream
# Levels: 1..1.New 1..1.Stream 3.EU.2.Stream
```

Aaahh. That's a little bit better. We now have three unique IDs... and `reshape()` seems to work.

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar=names(mydf)[c(1, 2, 4, 5)], 
        timevar="Channel")
#   ID Geo Brand Neworstream RevQ112.On-line RevQ212.On-line
# 1  1         1         New               5               0
# 2  1         1      Stream               5               0
# 3  3  EU     2      Stream              NA              NA
#   RevQ312.On-line RevQ112.Tele RevQ212.Tele RevQ312.Tele
# 1               1           NA           NA           NA
# 2               1           NA           NA           NA
# 3              NA            5            1            0
```

Comment: Ananda, isn't this missing `ID=1, Neworstream=Stream`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Arun, no you're not. Let me look at it again.

Comment: @Arun, I think it's because of the `NA` values in the "Geo" column.

Comment: Oh wow.. that's interesting. Hadn't come across this issue before using base `reshape`...

Comment: @Arun, me neither--perhaps it's to do with how it creates a unique ID when multiple columns are selected. Will explore more when it's not my bedtime.

Comment: @Arun, a quick glance points to `interaction` being the culprit here.

Comment: Ananda, I was just writing you that! :) I remember @flodel mentioning the [**potential danger with using `interaction`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245423/559784). Also [**here**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/25312/2013/6/22).